Gradle Build Error: Conflict Between Settings Repositories and Project Repositories in build.gradle.kts
I'm encountering an issue with my Gradle build in Android Studio. The build fails with the following error message:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Malek\AndroidStudioProjects\Course\build.gradle.kts' line: 16

What went wrong:
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'

Try:



Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'
at org.gradle.internal.management.DefaultDependencyResolutionManagement.repoMutationDisallowedOnProject(DefaultDependencyResolutionManagement.java:199)

This error suggests that my build configuration is set to prefer settings repositories, but a repository ('MavenRepo') was added in the project build file build.gradle.kts on line 16. I've tried running with the --info and --debug options but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Any suggestions on how to fix this conflict would be greatly appreciated.
I tried following a solution I found on YouTube, which suggested removing the repository declaration from the build.gradle.kts file. However, despite removing the MavenRepo repository as instructed, I am still encountering the same error. I expected this change to resolve the conflict between the settings repositories and project repositories, but the build continues to fail with the same message.
my gradle settings file :
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

    dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

    rootProject.name = "Course"
    include(":app")


build gradle kts file :
buildscript {
    val agp_version by extra("8.2.0")
    val agp_version1 by extra("8.2.2")
    val agp_version2 by extra("8.2.2")
}

    plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.10"
}

    dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


Can you post your settings.gradle.kts and build.gradle.kts files

Edit your question with the complete content of the file. Also read How to ask a question

You cannot have a repositories block inside the build.gradle.kts
This is because you have explicitly set
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

which indicates that you cannot define repositories anywhere other than the setttings.gradle.kts
If you observe your settings.gradle.kts you already have a repositories block there
Move all your repository urls over there...
You can read about the various repository modes here

You need to set your JVM version to 17 then, but that is not what your issue was

And yes, you cannot keep the repositories block outside the settings file

For Gradle JVM selection, see here

I didn't fully understand your suggestion. Are you saying I should remove the repositories block from the build.gradle.kts file and move all repository URLs to the settings.gradle.kts file? If so, which URLs are you referring to?
Additionally, when I remove the repositories block from the build.gradle.kts file, I encounter the following error:Gradle JVM version incompatible.
This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 11 but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17.

Ok, I will try that and I'll keep you updated. Thank you!

Thank you for your guidance! Removing the repository block from the build.gradle.kts file and using the Gradle JDK (gradle-local-java-home) finally fixed the problem. I really appreciate your help!

the gradle finally is working but unfortunately i'm encountering  now an "unresolved reference" error when using the println function in my main function , knowing that this problem didnot exist before the modification

Create a seperate question please

Yes i know, i've already done it, could you please check it on my account?

I resolved the issue by eliminating the repository block from the build.gradle.kts file and setting the Gradle JDK to gradle-local-java-home.
